# How to check if the next row in the file is empty?

Tags: ios, swift

I have this piece of code which reads my file line by line :

```
 data = try String(contentsOfFile: localFilePath as String,
                              encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)

 let myStrings = data.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())


 array = myStrings[0].characters.split(){$0 == ","}.flatMap{
        (Int(String.init($0).stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())))}
```

Here I am reading the first line of the file and converting the numbers in that line into `[Int]`.

Now I want to check if there are any numbers/letters in the next line of the file, however when i try and do this: `myStrings[1]` it gives me `Index out of range` rightfully so because the next line is empty.

My question is, is there a way to check if the next row in the file has any data, without getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you only do myStrings[1] and it already shows you "Index out of range" then it's probably that there is no string there (not even empty one). You should check if the index of string you are trying to access (1 in this example) isn't out of bounds of myStrings array.
On the other hand, if you actually get the error later and there is a string that might be empty you could use isEmpty() to check that.

Answer (score 0):

Check the number of lines you have first by using the `count` property on your `myStrings` array. This tells you how many items your array contains.